# VB.NET - Issue with 'Return' value on Async function

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, post, dotnet-httpclient

I'm currently developing an application in VB.Net (Visual Studio 2019) that will eventually run as a service and perform the daily task of reading several large .CSV format files, produced by our reporting system, convert the data into JSON format and submit it to a 3rd party via their API.

There are two steps to the API call

1. Submit login credentials in JSON format and receive a Bearer Token
2. Submit the JSON format data, with the Bearer Token in the header

After much messing around, I have managed to successfully implement and test the first part, but am having issues with retention of the Bearer Token once the function has exited.

Here's the function and the code where it's called...

```
   Private Async Function PostAsync(ByVal JSONString As String, ByVal EndPoint As String) As Task(Of String)
        Dim APIuri As New Uri(EndPoint)
        Dim Result As String

        AddLogEntry("Connecting to endpoint : " & EndPoint)

        Try
            With ZincClient
                .BaseAddress = APIuri
                .DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
                .DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
            End With

            Dim content As New Net.Http.StringContent(JSONString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

            AddLogEntry("Sending : " & JSONString & " to endpoint")
            Dim response As Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage = Await ZincClient.PostAsync(APIuri, content).ConfigureAwait(False)
            Result = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            AddLogEntry("Received : " & Result & " from endpoint")

            OAuth = Result                                                                                                     ' Set global variable to POST result string value - DEV & TEST ONLY

            Return Result
        Catch ex As Exception
            AddLogEntry("ERROR! - " & ex.InnerException.Message)
            Return ""
        End Try

    End Function

    Private Sub btnRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click
        Dim APILoginURL As String = "https://api5.cnx1.uk/consumer/login" ' Hard coded for DEV & TEST ONLY

        Try                                                                               ' Attempt login to Connext API
            AddLogEntry("Starting API transfer")                                          ' Record event in log array
            Dim userCreds = BuildLogin("FakeUser", "MadeUpPassword")                   ' Function call that returns user creds in JSON "key:value" format
            Dim POST_result = PostAsync(userCreds, APILoginURL)                           ' Make POST request
            MsgBox(OAuth)                                                                 ' TEST & DEV ONLY - this should contain the Bearer Token returned form the login request
        Catch ex As Exception
            AddLogEntry("ERROR! - Unable to connect to Connex API - " & ex.Message)       ' Record error in log array
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

I put a break point in the function and can see  in the debugger that the `Result` variable contains the token, but when the function exits, the `POST_result` variable in the calling `sub btnRun.Click()` is set to 'nothing'

I created a global variable of type `string` called `OAuth` and assigned `Result` to it and sure enough, `OAuth` contains the token data, but reverts to "" when the function exists.

I'm a older, returning developer and a lot of this is new to me, so I'm clearly doing something wrong or missing a vital piece of code.

I was informed that `HTTPClient` and Async was the way to go, but as my app will have no UI, should I consider another approach? In any case, I'd still like to fix this code as I'm hoping to eventually run this as a web service down the line.

All assistance and advice graciously welcomed.

Comment: Async requires await. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: What is the use of `OAuth = Result` here? You're returning `Result`, that's what you care about. Make `btnRun_Click` async and await the return value of `PostAsync()`: `Dim POST_result = await PostAsync(userCreds, APILoginURL)`. Remove that `OAuth` thing. If this is a WinForms app, also remove `.ConfigureAwait(False)` from `ZincClient.PostAsync()`, unless that library explicitly instructs to do so in this environment (if you have sample code for Console or Web, it doesn't probably apply to WinForms).

Comment: OAuth was for test purposes only and I've now resolved the problem. Many thanks for your input :).